# Fastest way to find and replace specific line in a large text file with Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, io, full-text-search

I have a `numbers.txt` file that consists of several 100K lines, each one made up of two unique digits separated with `:` sign:

```
407597693:1604722326.2426915
510905857:1604722326.2696202
76792361:1604722331.120079
112854912:1604722333.4496727
470822611:1604722335.283259
```

My goal is to locate a line with the number `407597693` on the left side and then proceed to change the number on the right side by adding `3600` to it. After that, I have to rewrite the `numbers.txt` file with all the changes. I must perform the same (just different number) operation on the same txt file as fast as possible.

I have managed to make it work via `with open:` file operations and `for` loop for each line, searching for the needed number, modifying the line, and then rewriting the whole file. However, I've noticed that constantly performing such an operation does take some time for my program, about 0.2-0.5 sec, which adds up over time and slows everything down considerably.

Here is the code I am using:

```
number = 407597693

with open("numbers.txt", "r+") as library:
                file = library.read()
            if (str(number) + ":") in file:
                lines = file.splitlines()
                with open("numbers_temp.txt", "a+") as library_temp:
                    for line in lines:
                        if (str(number) + ":") in line:
                            library_temp.write(
                                "\n" + str(number) + ":" + str(time.time() + 3600)
                            )
                        else:
                            library_temp.write("\n" + line)

                    library_temp.seek(0)
                    new_file = library_temp.read()

                    with open("numbers.txt", "w+") as library_2:
                        library_2.write(new_file)

                os.remove("numbers_temp.txt")
```

I would really appreciate any input on how to speed up this process, many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Plese back up and describe the actual use case.  I find it untenable that the object is to maintain a text file, making single-line updates on demand, dependent upon Python.  Can you make the changes in a batch?  Must you use Python?  Why is a text file required?  This appears much better suited to a data base application.

Comment: @Prune "Can you make the changes in a batch?" - Please clarify that question. " Must you use Python?" - Yes, since this is the language my complex program is built in. "Why is a text file required?" - Since users must have direct and easy access to the information + can be viewed offline + should not require any additional software to read and operate.

Comment: This isn't meant as a full answer, but I had a problem in which I had to pull of spefic operations in 250MB text files with particular boundary points indicating a new record structure.  I got *much* faster response by first calling subprocess `grep` to locate the lines ahead of time and then using Python to open and `seek` ing to those lines, rather than scanning the whole file in Python for those boundary points.  A good deal of the file's contents was of **no** interest between boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your memory can store the whole file. This should be faster by using regex:

```
import re
number = 407597693
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    # data = re.sub(f'({number}):(.*)', lambda x:f"{x.group(1)}:{float(x.group(2))+3600}", data)
    data = re.sub("^" + str(number) + ".*\n", str(number) + ":" + str(int(time.time()) + 3600) + "\n", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
with open("numbers.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Your answer was partially correct. While using regex reduced the time needed to complete the task by 4 times, your specific code didn't quite work for me. The part that I had to change is:  `data = re.sub("^" + str(number) + ".*\n", str(number) + ":" + str(int(time.time()) + 3600) + "\n", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)`.
I will mark your answer as a solution, but maybe you will want to change your line of code to mine since I tested it out, and it looks much simpler.

Comment: Oh yeah I put the `f` inside the string, it should be at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a memory mapped file, use a regular expression to find the line you want, and with any luck you'll only have to change one page in the file. I'm using the decimal module so that you don't have decimal to binary float conversion problems. Usually the new number and the old number will be the same width and file contents will not need to be moved. I'm showing a linux example. Windows `mmap.map` is a bit different but should be easy to use.

```
import mmap
import re
from decimal import Decimal

def increment_record(filename, findval, increment):
    with open(filename, "rb+") as fp:
        with mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0) as fmap:
            search = re.search(rf"{findme}:([\d\.]+)".encode("ascii"), fmap, 
                    re.MULTILINE)
            if search:
                # found float to change. Use Decimal for base 10 precision
                newval = Decimal(search.group(1).decode("ascii")) + increment
                newval = f"{newval}".encode("ascii")
                delta = len(newval) - len(search.group(1))
                if delta:
                    # need to expand file and copy
                    fsize = fmap.size()
                    fmap.resize(fsize + delta)
                    fmap.move(search.end(1) + delta, search.end(1), 
                        fsize - search.end(1))
                # change just the number
                fmap[search.start(1):search.start(1) + len(newval)] = newval

# test parameters
filename = "test.txt"
findme = "76792361"
increment = 3600

testdata = """407597693:1604722326.2426915
510905857:1604722326.2696202
76792361:1604722331.120079
112854912:1604722333.4496727
470822611:1604722335.283259"""

open(filename, "w").write(testdata)

increment_record(filename, findme, increment)

print("changes:")
for old,new in zip(testdata.split("\n"), open(filename)):
    new = new.strip()
    if old != new:
        print((old,new))
print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather that having to run multiple loops, we can do this in a single loop as under:

```
number = 407597693
numbers = ''
with open('numbers.txt', "r+") as inputfile:
    file = inputfile.read()

    if(file.find(str(number))) != -1 :
        for line in file.splitlines():
            if (line.find(str(number))) == 0:
                numbers += line.split(':')[0] + ':' + str(float(line.split(':')[1]) + float(3600)) + '\n'
            else:
                numbers += line + '\n'

    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as updatedFile:
    updatedFile.writelines(numbers)
```

Hopefully this shall help..